# Use ActionLink to increase value of property

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Please let me try to explain this as best as I can.

I have tried researching this but I don't know how to word it correctly to achieve what I am looking for.

I have this on my page:  [image: Example]

Now what I want to happen is when the user clicks 'Add Win' the value increases by 1 (so the value would be 5 if the user clicked the link).

I want this to happen instead of being redirected to my `Edit` View.  It seems to be pointless/tedious to have to fill out a form, & save the form when all I need to do is increase the value of this number by 1.

How do I go about doing this?

I haven't changed anything in my default controller `Edit` action so here it is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Team team = db.Teams.Find(id);
        if (team == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(team);
    }

    // POST: Teams/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,TeamName,TotalWins, SeriesWins")] Team team)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(team);
    }
```

So how do I use my `ActionLink` to increase the value of that number?

UPDATE:

HTML:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Win", "Edit", "Teams", new { id = 2 }, null)
<tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.TeamName == "example"))
                {
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <span id="teamLabel">
                           @item.SeriesWins
                        </span>

                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I won't give a full solution, but why you are not simply using ajax? That's what these xhr-objects are about. If you really want to use asp.net mvc then read about partial views. You are able to submit partials without to re-render total page again. maybe this can help you.

Comment: You should increment using javascript and then submit the form

Comment: @Fals I have posted an update to include my HTML.. how do I go about doing this with js and then submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an alternate solution.

I created a custom `ActionResult` in my controller to find the `id` and add +1 to the property that I need to address.

```
public ActionResult AddOne(int id)
    {
        Team team = db.database.Find(id);
        team.SeriesWins += 1;
        UpdateModel(team);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```